# Caribbean cruise with Indian Passport and German permanent residence permit with first port of entry : Dom. Rep

Tags: indian-citizens, caribbean, german-residents

Is the electronic residence permit card (written completely in German and without any specific mention of Schengen visa) considered as a valid visa?

Comment: Doesn't your card say "residence permit" in English on the front in the bottom right corner?  Also, why are you asking whether it is "considered as a valid visa?"  Are you referring to a specific list of requirements?  If so, which one?  (You must satisfy the document requirements both of your cruise operator and of the countries you wish to visit, after all.)

Comment: Thankyou for your comment. My question stemmed from the fact that unlike in the paper version of the visa, it isn't mentioned anywhere that I have a Schengen Visa on the electronic permit. For anyone interested, my electronic permit was enough for the trip.

Comment: Please post that information in an answer and accept it.

Comment: Is this a red and blue card with a bull and stars above your picture?

Answer (score 4):

For anyone interested, my electronic residence permit was enough for this trip (considering I was staying at the first port of entry for a period of less than 24 hours).